# What does collocate with "love" here?

Tags: collocations, idiomatic-language

According to one of the exercises in *collocation in use*, it says " strongly love", is not a correct collocation. 
Then what word suits the purpose? 
[Note; love functions as a verb here].

Deeply love, perhaps?

I deeply love . . . , or , I truly love . . . .

Comment: Love can be called "strong" (i.e. not fading or becoming less). But with an adverbial modifier of the verb, "deeply" is common and "strongly" is not really used.

Comment: You can use COCA and BNC to search for collocations.

Comment: Truly, madly, deeply all work (with thanks to [Savage Garden](https://youtu.be/WQnAxOQxQIU?t=4), but I think *unconditionally* does the best job

Answer (score 1):

There are perhaps hundreds of possibilities:  *love truly, love deeply, love madly, love immoderately, love unconditionally, love unreservedly, love desperately, love unremittingly*, and too many more to list here.

There's really no reason why "love strongly" is not used other than it's simply *not used* -- possibly because there are so many better options.